# How to build a database for android which is accessible by any android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am new at android programming. Now, I want to build a database for my application (application will just read data from it but wil not write anything) with a huge index number. As I see, building database in eclipse is not a good solution. Are there anyway to build a database from outside of the application (project), and put it into a file (maybe) in the application project file, and build this app and database by using related APK?

Any solution will also work, this is just a thought.
(I prefer SQLite)

Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SQLiteStudio for my applications. You can download it from here:
[SQLite Studio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/?act=download).
Here is a good tutorial how to use your own SQLite database in android:
[Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Also, you can try to use SQLiteManager (Firefox add-on) or SQLiteBrowser. You can add SQLiteBrowser plugin to eclipse and view database content from DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a desktop SQLite editor on my PC to build the database, then include the it as a resource in your app.

Google will lead you to plenty of SQLite editors.  i use SQLiteBrowser.

I do all of my DB design and initial loading/testing on my PC before moving it to Android. It's a lot easier and faster.